# Implementing a button to do what file menu item does

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I have a menu item `File -> Export`. When I select that menu item, an export dialog box comes up.

I want to implement a button in different views (eg. Home, Summary, etc.) that essentially has the same behavior as `File -> Export`. The file menu item is accessible under any view.

I notice the functions have the following: `function_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I would prefer to not to rehash code. I thought about creating a new instance, then passing the arguments, but `sender` and `e` would not be the same through the button as it would be through the file menu.

**Is there a way for the current view to access the file menu item (`File -> Export`) via a button?** Just having a function to implicitly access the file menu item alone would be ideal...parameter passing would get messy for something as simple as the end result.

Comment: Are you actually using the sender and event args, or are you just concerned about possibly needing them in the future?

Comment: I don't want to use the args. I also don't want to instantiate code elsewhere when it's not currently instantiated just to get a function to work (let alone properly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, the sender and event arguments for a button or menu click aren't something you're going to use.  As such, you can often just have a method that ALL of the event handlers reference, ie:  `ExportFile()`, and call it from each of them.

This way, there isn't duplicated (real) code, since the event handlers each just call a method that is shared.

Comment: Right, I don't want to touch the args. I am attempting to create a public function in the same file as the file menu item...do I call `function_Click(sender, e);`? Like I said, I don't want to touch the args, but how would I execute without doing so?

Comment: @edmastermind29 Inside of the event handler, you'd call the method:  `void function_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ExportFile(); }`